# Get a single value from a data frame in R

Tags: r

Say I have a data frame df such as :

```
col1 col2
x1   y1
x2   y2
```

with arbitrary values in each "cell".
How do I get a single value for a given cell ?

For instance to get the value of the cell in the first row and second column, doing this :

```
df[1,2]
```

works with numeric values, but with strings it return the levels as well.

What is the proper way of getting a single value (for instance for use in a condition for a subset of another data frame) ?

**EDIT**
More details about what I need this for. Say I need to use values from df to subset another data frame df2 :

```
subset(df2, (id == SomeCommand(df[1,1])) & (name == SomeCommand(df[1,2])))
```

Is there any such "SomeCommand" that would reliably return a single value (w/o levels) of the appropriate type regardless of the type of the columns in df ?

Comment: `as.character(df[1,2])`

Comment: @Ronak Shah : this doesn't work for anything else than a string, right ? Is there any "robust" way to get a single value no matter what type it is ? Perhaps my question wasn't clear enough.

Comment: What @RonakShah, you should coerce it to something other than `factor`. But in essence, it's still only one value.

Comment: @GuitarExtended no, it will coerce anything to character. This is more robust than say `as.numeric`, which will mess up factors (would return level _number_, not actual level value). That being said, you probably don't need to coerce to another type to use it for further subsetting.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik But wouldn't that be a problem if I wanted to use the result in a condition, say : `subset(df2, id == as.character(df[1,2]))`, where "id" is numeric.

Comment: @GuitarExtended you can include a more complete example indicating the issue.

Comment: @RonakShah I've just edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R will get out of its way to try to figure out what you want. If you coerce to character, it should work. Here's a quick example.

```
> xy <- data.frame(a = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3), b = factor(1:3), c = letters[1:3])
> 
> xy$a == 0.1
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
> xy$a == "0.1"
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
> xy$b == "2"
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
> xy$b == 2
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
> xy$c == "a"
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Which means that if `a` is numeric and `a == b`, then `a + b` may throw an error (for instance, `0.1 == "0.1"` is true and `0.1 + "0.1"` fails). I didn't know this one. And of course `0.1 == "0.1000000000000000000000000001"` is false but `0.1 == 0.1000000000000000000000000001` is true. Yet another "feature" I dislike in R. Very error-prone.

Comment: Not sure who is forcing you to use R, but do let me know their address. I will write a very staunchy letter to them.

Comment: I tried to point out a risk with this feature of R, that the reader passing by may not be aware of. Maybe it wasn't clear enough. Nobody forces me to use R, if anything, that would rather be the contrary. I use R a lot at work, I like it, that does not mean I have to be blind to its defects. Your comment is surprising.

Answer (score 4):

A common application is to obtain a particular value of one variable in a data-frame given the value of one or more other column variables in the same record. For this the "filter" command can be used. It may look clunky but it works well for a large data-frame.

```
library(dplyr)
df
   rnames col1 col2 col3
1   row1    1    3    a
2   row2    2    6    b
3   row3    3    9    c
4   row4    4   12    d
5   row5    5   15    e
```

To find the value of col1 given col3 = 'c'

```
a <- filter(df, col3=='c')  # can specify multiple known column values
a                           #produces a data-frame with the record(s)               
 rnames col1 col2 col3
1   row3    3    9    c     # which contains Col1 = 3
class(a)
[1] "data.frame"
```

But can get value of Col1 in one line

```
b <- filter(df, col3=='c')$col1   
b
[1] 3
 class(b)
[1] "numeric"
```

For a result with multiple values

```
c <- filter(df, col1 > 3)$col3  
c[1] "d" "e"            # list if  > 1 result
class(c)
[1] "character"
```

Answer (score 0):

One way that works is, defining the colClasses of your dataframe while creating it:
for example:

```
my_table = read.table("myfile.txt", sep=" ", colClasses = c("character", "character", "numeric"))
```